# Gitlab API - Create issue quietly?

Tags: python, gitlab

I'm using the gitlab python api to create issues, however as we are importing them from an excel sheet, it generates ton's of emails, is there a way to silently create an issue?

```
    import gitlab
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://gitlab.ourdomain.com', 'mytoken')
    issue = project.issues.create('title':'test', 'assignee_username', 'mchiles', 'assignee_id': 123)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible - there's no publicly-documented option in GitLab's [API Reference for Project Issue Creation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue) that allows for this type of functionality.

You may consider raising a feature request in their [issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/) for this.