# Gitlab issue - can it be auto created

Tags: gitlab

I have a automation test suite in gitlab, say 10 test cases, if any of the case fails, the gitlab issue has to be created automatically. Do we have any plugin or any for this.

Answer (score 1):

the [api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue) provides a possible solution:

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug`

in case the above description isn't sufficient, you could push this by creating a issue in their tracker.
Here's a link to the related issues
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=all&search=create+issue

Comment: somewhat related question with possible python example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012997/gitlab-api-create-issue-quietly